# How to dynamically return in each row the number of occurences of a string found in every column?

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have data between `H2:L` where H is static but L can grow to a new column.

How to use something dynamic like an `arrayformula` to count the number of occurrences of certain strings inside every column based on the row?

I'd like to be dynamic and not just a simple `countif` because the number of rows is dynamic.

For example, I'd like to return the numbers under **Testing** and **Foobar**:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  | Testing | Foobar |  | Header | Header | Header | Header | Header |
| 2 |  |  |  |  | 3 | 1 |  | Testing | foobar | Testing | hello | Testing |
| 3 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 |  | foobar | Testing | hey | yo | there |
| 4 |  |  |  |  | 2 | 0 |  | what | Testing | Testing | no | thanks |
| 5 |  |  |  |  | 0 | 0 |  | just | a | very | short | line |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to share what I managed to come out with, which has to involve multiple formulas:

1. In A2, I manually define the starting cell of the searched area.
2. In B2, I automatically calculate the searched area based on A2.
3. In C2, I automatically calculate the starting column based on A2.
4. Finally, E2 does the needed count based on B2 and C2.

I couldn't find a way to expand E2 to also look for what's in F1, so the only solution was to copy it left and right. The reason is that `IF(indirect($B2)=E1` can't be used if it's changed to `IF(indirect($B2)=E1:F1` despite the `arrayformula`.

The formulas are below:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Start Point (manual) | Range (auto) | Base col (auto) |  | Testing | Foobar |
| 2 | H2 | =concat(concat(A2, ":"), index(split(address(ROW(indirect(A2)), column(indirect(A2))+COUNTA(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(A2, ":", ROW(indirect(A2)))))-1, 2), "$"), 0, 1)) | =CONCATENATE(A2, ":", REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "[a-zA-Z]+")) |  | =ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(indirect($C2)),"",COUNTIF(IF(indirect($B2)=E1,ROW(indirect($B2))),ROW(indirect($C2))))) | =ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(indirect($C2)),"",COUNTIF(IF(indirect($B2)=F1,ROW(indirect($B2))),ROW(indirect($C2))))) |
| 3 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 |
| 4 |  |  |  |  | 2 | 0 |
| 5 |  |  |  |  | 0 | 0 |

which translates to:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Start Point (manual) | Range (auto) | Base col (auto) |  | Testing | Foobar |
| 2 | H2 | H2:L | H2:H |  | 3 | 1 |
| 3 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 |
| 4 |  |  |  |  | 2 | 0 |
| 5 |  |  |  |  | 0 | 0 |